# Can we check in a MODEL [CODIGNITER] whether a query returns true or false and based on it perform different operations like if else statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can we check in a MODEL [CODIGNITER] whether a mysql query returns true or false and based on the request in order to perform if else statement

A sql statement in model to perform whether if the sql statement gives num_rows>0 if it gives i need to perform a function else continue with other lines

Comment: Could you elaborate some more? The question isn't clear enough, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, here's a contrived example.

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function blog_exists( $id )
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM BLOG WHERE BLOG.ID = '. $id);

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
            return true; 
        else 
            return false; 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

no dat part of the code goes into controllers.You need to make another function in models which wud be called depending  on the true or false of the controller function.eg:-
In MOdels:-

```
<?php
function xyz($flag){
if(----)return true;
else return false;
function abc($flag){----};
function ghi($flag){----};
?>
```

In controllers:-

```
function call($var){
if(xyz($var)==TRUE) abc($var);
else ghi($var);
 ?>
```